# Check size of SQL datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a SQL datasource that I want to check every 15 seconds for a change in size. The datasource may start empty or with any amount of entries in it. Any time the size is different from the previous check I am trying to return some sort of flag so that I can use this to trigger a windows system notification. Being new to c# I am unsure of how to tackle this.

As suggested below, one way to track the number of entries in the data source would be to use `select count(*)`.

Where I am fumbling is how to write a c# function that looks at this SQL DataSource for a change in size. An idea in pseudocode below:

```
protected void checkSize(object sender, EventArgs e, SQL DataSource ds)
{
    int a = select count(*) ds
    //wait 30 seconds
    int b = select count(*) ds
    if b > a
        //trigger windows notification (outside of scope)
    else
        repeat

    repeat every 30 seconds
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *datasource* and by *size*? Do you mean *the number of rows returned by a specific query*? Do you care if the data returned has changed even if the "size" hasn't changed?

Comment: @Flydog57 the datasource is the result of a SQL query. The way it behaves it wont be possible for the data returned to change. And by "size" I think this can be done by number of rows returned OR actual size in memory of the data returned.

Comment: How are you writing this query? Straight-up ADO.NET, Dapper, Entity Framework? If your query looks like `select a, b, c from xyz where a=lmnop`, consider looking at the result of `select count(*) from xyz where a=lmnop`

Comment: @Flydog57 doing it stright-up ADO.NET. I understand the SQL side of things, just don't know how to write a c# function to work with it. Thanks for the `select count(*)` tip that will be very useful and help lean things out.

Comment: Look at Dapper - it's much easier to use (and less error-prone) than straight-up ADO.NET

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure that returns the count of items. Add this procedure to a SQL agent JOB that runs on a schedule (30 secs?). You can have the job email or alert you should the count be over a specific threshold.

@MaxB if you need to do it your way then you'll want to use a timer that tracks execution timing. The trigger will be on the checkbox selectedIndexChanged event. Note this approach can be expensive as it'll cause constant postbacks to the server and is susceptible to session timeouts, so you may want to check and increase your timeout variables. The better design would be to keep track in a database if the last event was a check or not, then on a new page load (user comes in to page at a later time) the checkbox will already be checked and the job still running. Where then the user can uncheck the box there by disabling the job.

Comment: I am trying to do everything on the web app side of things to avoid meddling with the database

Comment: @MaxB A web page is not the proper place to put code run every X seconds. Your code will ultimately only respond to client request, not run on demand. An agent job is a good place for this logic, as well as a separate service.

Comment: @Alejandro It is being set up to run while a checkbox is checked on the web page

Comment: What happens when that page is opened many times? Does it run once for each user? And it never runs if nobody has that page open and that checkbox ticked?

Comment: The page loads with the box unchecked and will only run while the box is checked. It will never run if the page isn't open or box unchecked